# Is it possible to load an extra helper .so during current gdb session?

Tags: c++, gdb

Is it possible to load an extra helper .so during current gdb session?

```
// point.h
class Point
{
public:
  int x;
  int y;
  Point(int x1, int y1) {x = x1; y = y1;}
};

// main.cpp
#include "point.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  Point p(3, 4);
  printf("%d\n", p.x);
  return 0;
}
```

g++ -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -g main.o -o main

When debugging, I need to add a helper function to dump the Point object. But I don't want to recompile and rerun. (It might take a long time.) So I am trying to build another helper.so.

```
// helper.cpp
#include "point.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void dump_point(Point *p)
{
  printf("Point(%d, %d)\n", p->x, p->y);
}
```

g++ -g -fPIC -shared helper.cpp -o helper.so

Is it possible to load this helper.so in gdb so I can call dump_point() without rerunning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When debugging, I need to add a helper function to dump the Point object.

The "normal" way to do this to write a custom [pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) in Python.

One advantage of doing that is that the pretty printer will also work for a `core` dump, whereas `dump_point()` solution will not (regardless of whether it's linked in or loaded from a separate `.so`).

> So I am trying to build another helper.so.

If your `main` was linked against `libdl`, you *could* do this:

```
(gdb) call dlopen("./helper.so", 0)
(gdb) call dlsym($_, "dump_point")
```

Note: you will *want* to make `dump_point` `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling.

Comment: The problem in pretty print is sometimes it can not direct call the existing helper function in the project. e.g. the existing function: void dump1(Point *p, std::string indent).  I can not call it in gdb: call dump1(p, "").  Pretty printer cannot either.
The dump1() could be complex, so it might not be worthwhile to reimplement it in python pretty printer.
The simplest way is to write another gdb-friendly helper function to call dump1().

Comment: @vicshen The `dump1()` solution will not work on a `core` dump (as I said before). Sooner or later you will need to, and then you'll have to write a Python pretty-printer anyway.